# How to use Symfony 2.6+ validation's payload with annotation?

Tags: php, symfony

I want use Symfony's (up from 2.6) payload attribute for Validations

(e.g. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/severity.html)

But when using it with annotations as they suggest like:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User
{
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(payload = {severity = "error"})
 */
protected $username;
}
```

What I get is an error telling me: [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant severity

I tried several other combinations like payload="{severtiy = 'error'}", payload=severity=error, payload=array('severity'=>'error') and others - nothing's working.

When using the payload in a YML it works like a charm.

Does anybody know how to use it with annotations? Thanks!

And of course, I have annotations working (validation:      { enable_annotations: true}), any other validation annotation works, it's just the payload attribute which is causing trouble.

Comment: anybody any idea? unfortunatley I don't see any other way to get support for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing quotes around your array key in the annotation. When an array key is not quoted, the Doctrine annotation parser considers you are trying to use PHP constant for the key.

```
@Assert\NotBlank(payload = {"severity" = "error"})
```

Comment: OK, then Symfony's documentation isn't correct here - do you know where I can let them know?

Comment: thanks, I created a pull request for the documentation